# CustomListView Click listener with Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've an issue with `onItemclicklistener`.
I'm getting real time data from firebase
What I want is, getting real time orders and when I click any specific order, it will go to another activity where specific details of that specific order should be shown.
How I get this?
`Switch Statements` will not work in this scenario.
How I get some id that will match in database, so that I can get that particular details.
I tried this method

```
       myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
String name=(String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                Intent i=new Intent(order.this,details.class);
               i.putExtra("CATEGORY", name);
        startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

and in details class

```
Intent i = new Intent();
String name=i.getStringExtra("CATEGORY");
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constans.CATEGORIES).child(name);
```

But it is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `ListView` contains the order names and the item on which the user click is the `name of the order`, to get that name of the order you need to use this code inside `onItemClick()` method:

```
String orderName = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Check Updated Code please

Comment: And? You say that  is crashing. What is the error from the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `item_id` with firebase notification and store it in the `listview` `adapter`.

Later you can pass this `id` to the new `activity` by putting in `extras`.